# Is Google Cloud Messaging Service required for push notifications

Tags: android, mysql, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking to create an Android app that uses a MySQL database located on a server. When certain changes are made to this database, I'd like a push notification to be sent to some app users. My question is, is the Google Cloud Messaging Service required to implement this? This page http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html seems to suggest that using the Google Developers Console is also required. If so, is it possible to export this project into Eclipse? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`My question is, is the Google Cloud Messaging Service required to implement this?`

Yes and no, if you want to do real push messages then yes it is required however if you dont want to use GCM you can use XMPP to send messages to devices

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "real" push messages?

Comment: Messages sent through google handled by google and received through google vs you having to do everything manually ie. setup servers handle xmpp user names and such

Comment: Okay - but my app is going to have its own user database hosted on a server, built in MySQL... would using GCM require the users to be Google users? Or does GCM handle basically just the pushing of the notifications part?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by `Google Users` if you use GCM its not going to go to Windows phone or iOS devices if thats what you mean. Each platform has their own push message service

Comment: By Google users I mean users that have Google Accounts (ie: the users in the app would be signed in with their Google accounts)

Comment: GCM is part of `Google Play Services` which in turn means that they need a google account which they create when the start the device for the first time. There is an old GCM library that you can download from the SDK Manager that you can use without google play services but like I said its old and there have been many fixes/improvements since then

Answer (score 0):

Push notification can be generated using alarm in android.See [this](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.in/2012/09/notification-in-android-using.html).

But here you are looking to send push notification after certain changes in your database which is located in your server,for that GCM will be a better option.You can find an excellent tutorial of GCM [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).